# How get URL of R Shiny application from web browser?

Tags: r, url, shiny

Let say there is R Shiny app by web address URL: http://127.0.0.1:7020/tests/test_one

```
library(shiny)

# How detect 'tests/test_one' here

# Running server
server <- function(input, output) { }
ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Shiny app"))
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

How it's possible to get in R Shiny code URL as a string "127.0.0.1:7020/tests/test_one" and then extract components "tests" and "test_one" from it BEFORE running 'server' code?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: use `session$clientData`. See example here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/client-data.html

Comment: Thanks! It seems what I was looking for.